# Dreamweaver Git integration not able to fetch

Tags: git, bitbucket, dreamweaver

I'm new to Git and have been experimenting with the platform over the past week or so. Dreamweaver is my code editor of choice and they have recently added Git compatibility, you are now able to with init or clone repositories from within the Site Settings page of the app.

I have successfully both initialised new repo's and cloned existing remote repo's. I am then able to stage, commit, push and pull to my remote BitBucket account.

However, the issue arises when trying to fetch from the remote repo, I get the following error message(s) and as I'm new to Git I'm wondering if this is a bug with DW, or if I'm missing something simple in the configuration?

I have downloaded the Sourcetree app and with this fetch appears to work correctly. I'd love to get DW working correctly however as then all changes / git activity can be seen at the same time as editing the code. The below error message don't appear to make much sense considering I can perform other actions successfully?

Error: git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@bitbucket.org': Device not configured
error: Could not fetch wordpress-blueprint

Many thanks,
Pete

Comment: Try doing this manually from the command line to see if there is a git issue. In a terminal / command window navigate to your git repo in question. Enter something like `git status` to see if git is working in that repo. If so try `git fetch` to see if it works ok...

Comment: Hi @code_fodder - thanks for the tip - how would I navigate to the repo in the command line?

Comment: I am not sure specifically for Dreamweaver (I never used that), but your git repo is the location on your PC where your source/project files are. E.g. in Eclipse on Windows it might be "C:\users\someuser\workspace\myProject\". Where the "myProject" folder is the git repo that was cloned - so inside there you will see the ".git" folder (hidden in win/linux so be sure to be able to view hidden folders).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of investigation it turns out this was a software specific bug with Dreamweaver v2017.5

After updating to v2018 the issue is resolved.